# visual studio slowness when web application references dll files on network file share

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In visual studio 2013, I have a web application project with references to a dozen or more dll files that are stored out on a network fileshare. So the reference paths look like \servername\sharename\folder\folder\binary.dll.

I've been trying to track down why visual studio has been so slow, and when looking at my windows resource monitor, I noticed that when I right-click any folder in the project to get a context menu, visual studio quits responding for 20-30 seconds, and during that time I see the system performing network activity with the server where those referenced dll files are located.

Anyone have an idea about what is going on here? Is it bad practice to reference dll files on a network share? Any tips or ideas for what I should try to get visual studio from stopping responding very very slowly like this?

Comment: Is your network IPv4 only or IPv6 compatible?

Comment: @Josh I'm not sure. Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: Turn off IPv6 on your machine and see if you can still get access.  If IPv6 is disabld on your network, Windows, by default, will try to navigate v6 first, before going down the v4 network.  This caused a slowness in our network for our developers.  Disabling the virtual IPv6 to IPv4 network tunnel fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's really a bad practice to reference dll files on a network share... latency will just drive you crazy!

Use Nuget to manage your own dependencies.

Comment: I created my own nuget package and source and used that instead of the network references. Works like a charm, and no more delay in VS! Thanks